# Magento Error when item list to Ebay

Tags: magento-1.9, m2epro

I am trying to list and item to Ebay but it showing error. Please find the below screenshot.

[image]

thanks

Comment: m2epro has good documentation and good support  - have you tried them first?

Comment: yes i tried but it is showing the same error

Comment: show us the MPN value

Comment: 846127172356 this is MPN value

Comment: Are other products with similar MPNs (e.g no of characters) listing OK?

Comment: no actually each product has unique MPN value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64174/discussion-between-jscar-and-raghu).